# Draw street using leaflet and osm

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm trying to create a map which will show streets (roads, paths...) in some context.
I only found how to draw polygons and ploylines, but drawing a street, with curves, using some sort of street-Id or geographical data, this I couldn't figure.

Is it even possible? or do I need to switch from leaflet?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> drawing a street, with curves, using some sort of street-Id or
>   geographical data

Using leaflet (or any other front-end library), there is no direct way to transform geographical data (I suppose you mean lat-lon points) into street polylines. And there is a reason for this: leaflet does not "understand" the geometry of the roads from raster tiles.

However, you can still add street polylines to your OSM basemap with the actual street geometry, using lat-lng coordinates but you will need to use an API.

This process is called **map matching** and there are several APIs that to this (not free). You send raw data (lat-lng coordinates) to the API and you get a response of a polyline that is matched to the actual OSM road geometry. Search for *OSM Map Matching API* and you will totally find some APIs to start with.

You could also implement your own back-end solution. One of the above APIs, the Open Source Routing Machine (http://project-osrm.org/) lets you build your own back-end service. You could go even further and build a custom back-end solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I'm trying your method, but my data type is called "GEOMETRY" or "GEOM_LINE" and its just a long base16 string.  
Do you happen to know what can I do to use it as you described? in some DBs there's a feature that the user can click an eye icon and see polyline on a map.

Here's an example:
0102000020E610000009000000DDCF29C8CF6E4140E010AAD4EC2740400342EBE1CB6E4140EEEC2B0FD2274040E4F560527C6E41405C2041F163264040F50F2219726E41403E93FDF3342640402E55698B6B6E4140B40419011526404068B114C9576E4140B9C2BB5CC4254040897D0228466E414063D34A2190254040D865

Comment: How did you get that string? Which API did you use?

Comment: It seems like the string you have is the PostGIS geometry type (geometry hex). If you use PostGIS, you could use the ST_AsGeoJSON() function to convert it to GeoJSON and add it to your map. But I am not sure I understood your question. Do you just want to add the above geometry in your leaflet map?

Comment: Eventually yes, I want to add a layer of geometric information. I'm just not quite sure how to do it with the given string because I'm not the one to produce it, but I'm using your information about the string to communicate with the guy who sent them to me, so thank you very much (!) and I hope he will be helpful using the ST_.. function.